# Java Glass Quickstart Project not working on App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-mirror-api, google-glass

The quickstart app started acting strangely for me.  I can't auth any users.  I'm getting the below error.  This works fine locally though.  Anyone know how to fix this or get around it?

Here's where it's happening in the code (AuthServlet:55)

```
 LOG.info("Got a code. Attempting to exchange for access token.");

 AuthorizationCodeFlow flow = AuthUtil.newAuthorizationCodeFlow();
  TokenResponse tokenResponse =
      flow.newTokenRequest(req.getParameter("code"))
          .setRedirectUri(WebUtil.buildUrl(req, "/oauth2callback")).execute();
```

Uncaught exception from servlet
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Timeout while fetching URL:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.convertApplicationException(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:141)
    at com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceImpl.fetch(URLFetchServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.google.api.client.extensions.appengine.http.UrlFetchRequest.execute(UrlFetchRequest.java:75)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:980)
    at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:299)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:175)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.execute(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:78)
    at com.google.glassware.AuthServlet.doGet(AuthServlet.java:55)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug in App Engine and the Google OAuth endpoints. It's being tracked in the [Glass issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=99). You can star that issue to receive updates as the investigation proceeds.

In the mean time, check out the [.NET](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-dotnet) and [PHP](https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-php) quick starts. They're working great.

Answer (score 1):

Google has had some intermittent connectivity issues over the last two days.  It appears to be working fine now.

See reports on the Google App Engine downtime notification group

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-appengine-downtime-notify/TqKVL9TNq2A